# Print jump 2 papers by print

Tags: delphi, printing

i'm creating a application who reads a txt file, and send for a second form, then i printscreen the form, and print then
code above:

```
count := form1.Memo1.Lines.Count;

gerarcodigo create a barcode.
var y,i : integer;
begin
begin
   for i := 0 to count do
   begin
    button1.visible := false;
    label1.caption := form1.memo1.lines[i];
    label2.Caption := form1.memo7.lines[i] ;
     label9.Caption := form1.memo2.lines[i];
     label10.Caption := form1.memo3.lines[i];
    label11.Caption := form1.memo4.lines[i];
     label13.Caption := form1.memo5.lines[i];
    label14.Caption := form1.memo6.lines[i];
    GerarCodigo(label1.caption, Image1.Canvas);
   PrintScale :=  poNone;
   Print;
   end;
```

but the problem is after print the frist one, the print left 2 paper blank, so then print the right infomation, and repeat until finish.

For more explication, i try to draw something.
when i try to print,

What can i do, to solve this problem?
i'm using argox printer for now.

[image]

Comment: I've read your post several times, but I don't understand what you are asking. Maybe it's just me. What does `GerarCodigo` do? What is `count` a member of?

Comment: gerarcodigo create a barcode, count, count the lines of memo.

Comment: I can't replicate. My printer spits out exactly one sheet per loop cycle. There is something else than the code you have shown, that causes the extra pages. Maybe in printer settings (just a guess).